# Passing a list of object in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack, swagger, swagger-ui

I have created a customer service using ServiceStack but i am not able to pass a list of object from this method.

**Customer Service -**

```
public class EntityService : Service
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Request for entity information list
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="request"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public object Any(List<CustomerRequest> request)
        {

        }

}
```

**Request DTO -**

```
  [Route("/api/V1/GetCustomerDetails", Verbs = "POST", Notes = "")]   
    public class CustomerRequest : IReturn<List<CustomerResponse>>
        {
           [ApiMember(Name = "GetCustomerDetails", Description = "GetCustomerDetails", ParameterType = "body", DataType = "List<BaseRequest>", IsRequired = true)]
          List<BaseRequest> _baseRequest {get;set;}
        }

public class BaseRequest
{
            public string CustId { get; set; }

            public string CustName { get; set; }    

            public string CustAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Could you please let me know what is the correct way to pass list of object in ServiceStack Post operation.

Answer (score 4):

Each Service in ServiceStack needs to accept a single named concrete Request DTO Type. You can look at the [AutoBatched Requests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-Batched-Requests) for how to send multiple requests.

E.g, if you want to a Service to accept a List of Types you can inherit `List<T>`, e.g:

```
public class CustomerRequests : List<CustomerRequest>{}

public class EntityService : Service
{
    public object Any(CustomerRequests request)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question with a BaseRequest class.So could please confirm if this is the correct way to execute?

Comment: @intelliCoder No all properties should be public and you shouldn't be exposing names starting with `_` in your public API as having a `_baseRequest` property means your Service is expecting JSON like `{"_baseRequest":[{"CustId":1},{"CustId":2}]}` which is ugly.

Comment: @intelliCoder have a look at [Designing APIs section](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki#documentation) in the ServiceStack docs, it walks through examples of creating Services with ServiceStack.

Comment: @mythz If I have a third party service sending an array to my API (not wrapped in an object), is there any way to accept that on my end with ServiceStack?

Comment: @JMK ? This answer shows how, have your Request DTO inherit a List.